# python string formatting

Tags: python

I want to execute a git command, in shell it is as below:

```
$ git log v2.6.38..v2.6.38-rc8 --pretty=format:%s%n%n
```

the --pretty=format:%s%n%n is to say only show the commit subject message, and every message is split by two new line.

now, I want to execute in python script, and input tag name as parameter.

I want do like this:

```
git_cmd = "git log %(old_tag)s..%(new_tag)s --pretty=format:'%s%n%n'"
git_cmd = git_cmd % {'old_tag'='v2.6.38','new_tag'='v2.6.38-rc8'}
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(git_cmd))
```

bug it go wrong, because %s%n%n is now interpret as a string format.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) (if you're using at least Python 2.6):

```
git_cmd = "git log {old_tag}..{new_tag} --pretty=format:'%s%n%n'"
git_cmd = git_cmd.format(old_tag='v2.6.38',new_tag='v2.6.38-rc8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the Python format strings by repeating the `%` twice.

For example:

```
git_cmd = "git log %(old_tag)s..%(new_tag)s --pretty=format:'%%s%%n%%n'"
```

Comment: thank you , it solve the problem.and it seems have to add a r head to the string .

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the string with `r` like this:

```
r"git log %(old_tag)s..%(new_tag)s --pretty=format:'%s%n%n'"
```

See the documentation on [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: The r will also prevent the %(old_tag)s and %(new_tag)s from working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just missing the dictionary syntax:

```
d = {'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Here it is applied to your code sample:

```
git_cmd = "git log %(old_tag)s..%(new_tag)s --pretty=format:'%s%n%n'"
git_cmd = git_cmd % {'old_tag':'v2.6.38','new_tag':'v2.6.38-rc8'}
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(git_cmd))
```